# Center of gravity 1/4 sphere

Tags: integration

I am solving problem, where i have to find the center of gravity of homogenus 1/4 of a sphere ($x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 ; x,y > 0)$. I Know that the center is in $xy$ plane on $y=x$. So I just tried to calculate the $r_T$. So I am trying to use integral in spherical coordinates:
$$
r_T= \frac{\int \int \int_V \rho r dV}{\int \int \int_V \rho dV}
$$
Is this the valid way, because I don't know how to use Jacobian matrix in this formula. What I am asking is if we can determine position of centre of gravity  with that equation only for Cartesian coordinates ($x,y$ and $z$) or for position of mass centre for any coordinate system, eg. for any new coordinates $q$:
$$
q_T= \frac{\int \int \int_V \rho q dV}{\int \int \int_V \rho dV}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The $x$-coordinate of the center can be integrated in spherical coordinates as

\begin{align}
x_c & = \frac1{\frac14\cdot \frac{4\pi}3} \int_{V} xdV\\
&=\frac3{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1
(r\cos\phi\sin\theta)r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi\\
&= \frac3{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\phi d\phi
\int_0^\pi\sin^2\theta d\theta \int_0^1 r^3dr \\
&= \frac38\\
\end{align}

and $y_c=x_c$. Thus, the center of gravity is $(\frac38, \frac38, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go about this in the usual way. I'll use $\mathbf{r}$ as a generic position vector and $\mathbf{r}_{\text{C.O.M}}$ to denote the position vector of the center of mass. We expect that the answer should be something like $$\mathbf{r}_{\text{C.O.M}}=\frac{1}{M}\iiint\limits _{\Omega } \rho \mathbf{r}\mathrm{d} V$$
Where $\Omega$ is our region and $M$ is our total mass. Since this region has constant density and is a quarter-sphere, $M$ is easy to calculate - it is simply $\frac{4\pi\rho}{3}$. We can now cancel out the $\rho$ in the numerator and denominator to be left with $$\mathbf{r}_{\text{C.O.M}}=\frac{3}{4\pi }\iiint\limits _{\Omega }\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d} V.$$
Now let's focus on that nasty looking triple integral. I'm going to convert to spherical polar coordinates and use the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ convention. We know that in polar spherical coordinates, $$\mathrm{d}V=r^2\sin(\phi)\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi.$$
And our position vector is simply $\mathbf{r}=r\hat{\mathbf{r}}$.

What about the bounds of our integral? Well, it is fairly obvious that $r$ will range from $0$ to $1$, $\theta$ will range from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and $\phi$ will range from $0$ to $\pi$. Converting $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ into the standard basis, we have:
$$\mathbf{r}_{\text{C.O.M}}=\frac{3}{4\pi}\int\limits ^{\pi }_{0}\int\limits ^{\pi /2}_{0}\int\limits ^{1}_{0}r(\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\hat{\mathbf{i}}+\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\hat{\mathbf{j}}+\cos(\phi)\hat{\mathbf{k}})r^{2}\sin( \phi )\mathrm{d} r\mathrm{d} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi .$$ 
Split the integral into $\hat{\mathbf{i}}$,$\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ components and take it from here.

EDIT: I acknowledge this is a rather long way of doing it. I tried to be as formal as possible to really show the spirit of volume integrals in different coordinate systems.

Comment: No errors, but doing integrals with noncartesian unit vectors can be a pain since the integral in question is now nine integrals. OP's original method of trying to find the average $s$ where $s$ is the cylindrical radial coordinate would've been more convenient.

Comment: The position vector in spherical coordinates is just $\mathbf{r} = r\mathbf{\hat{r}}$, not what you wrote. Also you can't just split the integral into various components because in spherical coordinates, the basis vectors change from point to point. The simplest way to setup the integrals is write everything in cartesian coordinates first and then apply the change of variables theorem to spherical coordinates, if desired.

Comment: Thanks all for your corrections. I will implement changes.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi In hindsight, this is a much more efficient way of solving this problem.